# Settting tite bar color of custom pynodes

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, pynodes

How does blender determine what the title bar color of a node will be? The theme has color settings for each node category, but what determines which category a node is in for selecting its color? There doesn't seem to be any obvious property any where that would control it...

My custom nodes all get the color of the 'inputs' category, which I'm guessing is the default. But I would really like to be able to either have them match up with the different inbuilt color categories or perhaps set my own preferences for their title bar color.

Is this something that is possible, or are custom nodes just forced into using the 'inputs' category color?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, all title bar [colors](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/commit/ad648a83ac611b955b9f86b8403a262a33a03ecb/source/blender/blenkernel/BKE_node.hh#L404) are [hard-coded](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/commit/ad648a83ac611b955b9f86b8403a262a33a03ecb/source/blender/editors/space_node/node_draw.cc#L1071), so at the very least you definitely can't change them colors to any of your own.

See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/306051/156014