# How to change the color of my custom node's label

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

My extension uses nodes and I would like to be able to change the color of their label. At the bottom of the page is a picture of what I'm talking about

[image]

Comment: The color of the header can't be edited, only the body. Set [`use_custom_color`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.use_custom_color) to true and then assign the [`color`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.color)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. See more
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/69086
and here
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/105102